# How to move RBS (FileStream BLOB Provider) from SQL server's C: drive to another drive?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sharepoint-2010, blob

I have set RBS (FileStream BLOB Provider) on SQL server's C: drive.
Now I want to shift the RBS to D: drive. Please guide me in this matter.

Comment: why can't you share what/How you tried ? where are you failing ? this things helps to suggest some thing, this is not an Exam answer sheet to write query couple of times when we dint know answer :-) .Please update other wise query will be flagged and closed as off topic soon

Comment: I came to know about the terms 'BLOB' and 'RBS' yesterday itself when our client asked us to come up with a 
solution for database optimisation.As of now, I am a total newbie to these and hence trying to come up 
with a solution by taking help from experts and browsing the internet. Also, I am afraid that if i try to make 
any change with my half-baked knowledge to the existing RBS on C: drive , I might make a mess of it.That's why,
waiting for concrete solution.